# Ember JS Filter model where title contains keyword

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to set up a search for a book in a library. Right now I have the search working where if the title and the keyword match it will return the result, however how can I make it so if the title contains the keyword it will return the result.

For example if the user searches for "The Adventures" they will get both "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn" and "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer"

This is my router right now which will find an exact match:

```
Books.BooksSearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.filter('book', function (book) {
            return book.get('titleSlug') == params.keyword;
        })
    },
    renderTemplate: function (controller) {
        this.render('books/index', { controller: controller });
    }
});
```

I have tried doing this using a javascript indexOf function, but it always returns no matches

```
Books.BooksSearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.filter('book', function (book) {
            return book.get('titleSlug').indexOf(params.keyword) > 0;
        })
    },
    renderTemplate: function (controller) {
        this.render('books/index', { controller: controller });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want `> -1`, because `0` is still a valid match.

For example:

```
"foo bar".indexOf("foo"); // returns 0
"foo bar".indexOf("lorem"); // returns -1
```